# Javascript to get entire contents of frame

Tags: javascript

I want to have a script rewrite a simple text-file opened up as the source of a frame -- one that lacks any html.  I tried `frames[1].document.innerHTML` but without success.  I even tried `.outerHTML` and got nothing.  Can I either (a) get from the frame the entire contents of the frame to manipulate using the script and then `.write()` back the result to the frame?   Or (b) add `<html>` and `<div>` tags, wrapping the document so I can get the inner html and then manipulate that?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try crossdomain.xml (google for it). I am assuming that BOTH the html files (parent page & frame'ed page) are owned by you.

Answer (score 7):

As long as your main page and iFrame page follow [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can access frame's html like this:

```
window.frames['iframe01'].document.body.innerHTML
```

or

```
window.frames['iframe01'].contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML
```

**To write:**

```
window.frames['iframe01'].contentDocument.write("[content here]");
```

Comment: Make sure the iframe is loaded before you access to its DOM.

Comment: That's just picking up the HTML, i.e. anything inside `<html>` tags.  But the document I want to manipulate has no tags at all.  It's just a text file.  As for write, I don't want to overwrite the existing document.  I was considering writing `<html>` tags at the top and bottom.

Comment: Most browsers will do that for you (as long as your `contentType` is `text/plain`).