# Javascript: Get body of an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to get body content of `iframe` using either Javascript or jQuery. I have tried to solve the problem several ways, but none of them worked for me.

The solutions I tried looked like these:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').document.innerHTML;

$("#content").contents().find("body").html();
```

Comment: why would either of those work? you're just getting the html as a result, you have to actually set it to something

Comment: yap im printing it in alert box like alert($("#content").contents().find("body").html());

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770704/javascript-to-get-entire-contents-of-frame

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is from the same domain, you could do an `$.ajax` request on the URL that is the iframe src url?

Comment: @AyazAliKhatri - Then you will get a cross domain security error. You will not be able to get the iframe's HTML in such a case.

Comment: yap im getting this error of permission in browser console :p. is there any way to do this

Comment: Fetching (wget/curl) that URL from the server side is the only viable option.

Comment: any example how to do this